# PreparedStatement.executeQuery fetches wrong value for some columns

Tags: java, oracle, executequery

When I execute a query using `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()` from a Java application I get a `resultSet` object with wrong values for some of the fields. When I use PLSQL developer then the value looks ok.

The field value is `10101010` but in the resultSet it's `1$ffssff`. The database field size is only 8 bytes but the result value I get is 9 bytes (and totally wrong). The type for this field is `VARCHAR2(8 BYTE)`

This only happens sometimes. Other times when I execute the same query I get the correct value.

How is it possible that resultSet fetches the wrong value for some of the fields ? Are there some settings I need to verify for this?  My `NLS_RDBMS_VERSION` is `11.2.0.3.0`.

Do you think it's a Java side problem or Oracle side data fetching problem?

Please let me know if you need additional details.

Comment: If you can run the query over and over again in SQL developer and keep getting the correct results then you have a java issue of some kind. Not aware of any bugs on the Oracle side. Usually these are type conversion or code page issues.

Comment: Can you show your Java code, and version, in case you're just doing something slightly wrong?

Comment: protected ResultSet exePreparedQuery(Connection conn, String query, ArrayList params)
 {
          PreparedStatement stmt = null;
      ResultSet rs = null;
   
          try {
   

              stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
              bindParametersValues(stmt, query, params);
              rs = stmt.executeQuery();
           
           catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
           }

     return rs;
 }

Comment: Hi  TheMadDBA -- if it is code page page issues then it should be consistence, right? In my case it happened only some times...

Comment: Java version is 1.6.0_23